# Ruby on Rails Regex Invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a regex for correct username validation in Ruby on Rails but for some reason I am doing something incorrect where all username inputs are invalid.  I am allowing for upper-case characters, lower-case characters, numbers, and underscores.

Ruby on Rails name validation regex code:

```
validates :name, :format => {:with => /\A[A-Za-z\d_]\z/}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Try using capital \Z or try with ^ and $ instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# \A[A-Za-z\d_]\z
# 
# Options: ^ and $ match at line breaks
# 
# Assert position at the beginning of the string «\A»
# Match a single character present in the list below «[A-Za-z\d_]»
#    A character in the range between “A” and “Z” «A-Z»
#    A character in the range between “a” and “z” «a-z»
#    A single digit 0..9 «\d»
#    The character “_” «_»
# Assert position at the very end of the string «\z»
```

This is your expression. Do you really want to match a single character?

I believe that :

```
/^\w+$/
```

this is what you are looking for. \w is a shorthand character class for what you have written. The above regex will match a string which consists only of A-Za-Z0-9_

Answer (score 3):

```
validates :name, :format => {:with => /^[A-Za-z0-9\_]+$/}
```

Nice page to test regular expressions in ruby: http://rubular.com/

Comment: I do not think that an empty string should validate. Do you?

Comment: except... for replacing the `\A\z` with `^$`
see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#regular-expressions